# Applying for Schengen (France) visa in US (Proof of socio-economic status)

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork, us-residents

I am an Indian citizen with a US Green Card and I reside and work in the USA as a university professor. I am planning on applying for a short stay Schengen visa (France) for tourism. The French Consulate with jurisdiction is Chicago.

To apply for a short stay Schengen visa the following documents are [mentioned](http://www.consulfrance-chicago.org/Short-stay-visa-for-tourism-business-or-family-visit) under "proof of socio-economic status":

- letter of employment in the U.S. confirming your salary, hire date, position and dates of vacation (business registration if self employed)
  and your last 3 pay stubs (unless downloaded, please bring a photocopy)
- or letter from your school or university confirming your enrollment status, attendance and expected graduation date
- For a business trip: please present a letter from your employer or University regarding the purpose of your trip and an official invitation from your hosting company in France

Now, I wish to not ask my university for a letter since I do not need them to know where I am vacationing during "off school" season.  I **also have a prior long stay French visa (*chercheur scientifique*) in my Indian passport (2014-2015)**.  I also have sufficient funds and of course plan on having travel arrangements etc. made before I apply for a visa.

This lack of "letter from employer": would it play negatively in the visa process?

Comment: Does  the letter have to say anything about where you are going? Can't you get a "To whom it may concern" letter stating the dates of your "off school" season and that you will be continuing your work as a professor starting on date X?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Inter-departmental politics.... Given the current season of inter-departmental politics that's going around at my university, there is a strong fear that faculty may leave this university and country and go to another country.  I suppose it would seem like I am stuck as a result of my passport refusing me free travel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can play negatively. If a consular officer is looking for an excuse to deny you, that is a perfect and legitimate opportunity.

The employer letter with vacation dates and declaration that your position is available for  you to resume after your vacation is a very strong tie to the home country (in this case USA).

You could also be approved without the letter, even unemployed people do get approved, however it is a good criteria on which to deny you if the officer so chooses. You can't take chances with visas despite you good immigration profile/history.

Comment: You provide a really good point of view on the "excuse for denial" aspect.  Thank you.